# Creating a list of contingency tables from variables in a data frame using for loop and if statement?

Tags: r, list, for-loop, if-statement, apply

Sample of data frame:

```
 WasAdmitted concldur ArrivalDayWdWe IMDQuintile log_depdur
           1      130        Weekend          Q1   5.480639
           1      177        Weekday          Q1   5.370638
           0      125        Weekday          Q2   4.828314
           1      102        Weekday          Q5   5.220356
           1      203        Weekday          Q4   5.402677
           0      168        Weekday          Q2   5.123964

sample <- structure(list(WasAdmitted = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), concldur = c(130L, 
177L, 125L, 102L, 203L, 168L), ArrivalDayWdWe = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Weekday", "Weekend"), class = "factor"), 
    IMDQuintile = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Q1", 
    "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), class = "factor"), log_depdur = c(5.48063892334199, 
    5.37063802812766, 4.8283137373023, 5.22035582507832, 5.40267738187228, 
    5.12396397940326)), class = "data.frame")
```

I have `WasAdmitted` as my binary dependent variable of interest. I would like to produce a list of contingency tables of `WasAdmitted` against all other variables in my data frame, which are either type factor, integer or character, in to a list of the resultant contingency tables. So I'm excluding numeric variables.

As a start, I've created this:

```
for (i in sample){
if (typeof(i) %in% c("integer", "factor", "chr"))
  return(table(sample$i, sample$WasAdmitted))
}
```

However I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to produce the tables after getting just the non-numeric columns.

```
inx <- sapply(sample, inherits, "numeric")
contg <- lapply(sample[!inx][-1], table, sample[!inx][[1]])

contg[1]
#$concldur
#     
#      0 1
#  102 0 1
#  125 1 0
#  130 0 1
#  168 1 0
#  177 0 1
#  203 0 1
```

**EDIT.**

If you want to use this result to compute something, you can `*apply` the function of your choice to each of its members.

For instance, in order to compute Chi-Squared tests of every table:

```
chiq_list <- lapply(contg, chisq.test)
```

This is the same as running one `chisq.test` on each of the 3 members of the result `contg`.

```
length(contg)
#[1] 3

chisq.test(contg [[1]])
chisq.test(contg [[2]])
chisq.test(contg [[3]])
```

You can then extract what you want from the test results list.

Here is how you would extract the test statistics.

```
sapply(chiq_list, '[[', 'statistic')
#      concldur.X-squared ArrivalDayWdWe.X-squared 
#            6.000000e+00             4.252453e-32 
#   IMDQuintile.X-squared 
#                     NaN
```

Or the p-values.

```
sapply(chiq_list, '[[', 'p.value')
# concldur ArrivalDayWdWe    IMDQuintile 
#0.3062189      1.0000000            NaN
```

Comment: Could I do something similar with using `chisq.test`? So I want to create a list of all the chisq.test results of `WasAdmitted` against `concldur`, `IMDQuntile`, etc. but not numeric vectors like `log_depdur`.